# Article necessary with "secret"?

Tags: articles

Is it necessary to use an article with the word *secret*?

For example:

> Teach your children not to keep problems, games, or other activities a secret.

or

> Teach your children not to keep problems, games, or other activities secret.

and

> If your kids go out for ice cream with a grandparent—even though you wouldn't approve—the grandparent shouldn't tell the kids to keep the ice cream a secret from you.

or

> If your kids go out for ice cream with a grandparent—even though you wouldn't approve—the grandparent shouldn't tell the kids to keep the ice cream secret from you.

Comment: The context you're asking about is very specifically the verb usage *to **keep** [something] **secret***. It's really a stylistic choice whether to include the indefinite article (in which case *secret* is a noun) or not (in which case *secret* is an adjective). FWIW I wouldn't use an article in the first example because it clashes with the fact that we've got a list of *multiple* "secrets".

Comment: To expand on @FumbleFingers' comments, *keep [noun] a [noun]* and *keep [noun] adjective* are both possible sequences in English. For example, you can *keep something safe,* or you can *keep somebody a prisoner*.

Comment: @Peter Shor You can also _keep somebody prisoner_. I think this one is best not analysed beyond the 3-word (assuming 'him' or 'Nelson' rather than 'the former President' etc) idiom; deciding the word-class of prisoner would probably warrant a doctorate.

Comment: @Lacey: I've flagged the question to see if the mods will migrate it to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (where I think it belongs). You can in fact ***hold** someone **prisoner*** with or without the article, so the specific words *keep* and *secret* aren't particularly significant here. But you can't *keep someone **a** safe,* and a decent answer for a learner might need to explain why that is. I have little interest in posting an ELU-type answer that simply says *"The article is just a stylistic choice in OP's exact contexts"*.

Comment: The truth is that although I can confidently say in this case it's optional whether to include the article, I don't know how to explain *why* both versions are "correct, grammatical, syntactically valid". Not that many words can be used as either noun or adjective as in *"It is [a] secret"*, and they don't all work exactly the same (for example, *"He is **a** prisoner"* requires the article).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suspect that most speakers of any language cannot explain most of the rules of their language, they just know them intuitively as a result of a lifetime of using the language. You can't explain _why_ certain verbs have nonstandard conjugations (it's just historical), but since all fluent English speakers know them, a question about them would go to ELL.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, I think that to a considerable extent you *can* explain "non-standard verb conjugations". There aren't many irregular verbs left in English, and almost all the "survivors" are only tenaciously hanging on because they're such common words. I'm sure a linguist/grammarian could identify some common characteristics in usages such as *keep it [a] secret, hold him [a] prisoner*. But I don't know if it's the same basic principle as *give her [a] breakfast*, or something more subtle.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A linguist could, I doubt that most lay people (outside the type of people who frequent forums like this) could. Ask some random person why _to be_ has irregular conjugation, they won't be able to answer, they'll just say something like "It's just different".

Comment: @Barmar: Precisely! So I'm now a bit ambivalent about this question. I think the basic *"Is it necessary to use an article here?"* question is a better fit for ELL, but the longer it hangs around "unanswered and unmigrated", the more I'm becoming interested in the broader question of *the general class of such constructions*. That's to say - which "verb + object + [**a** ???? (noun)] OR [???? (adjective]" combinations allow such usages, and what if anything do the relevant ***verb*** and ***????-word*** elements have in common?

Comment: @Edwin: the OED doesn't mention *"keep somebody prisoner"*, but it handles the question of what the part of speech is in the similar expression *"take somebody prisoner"* by avoiding the question: it lists it under *"phrases"*.

Comment: @Peter I think the OED just gets better. You can argue that 'take [X] prisoner' is a (usually, in fact almost obligatorily) separable transitive MWV (= capture). Similarly for 'keep prisoner' (almost = hold). With expressions like 'weigh anchor', it is more difficult to posit a MWV, but there still seems a large departure from a V + DO structure (*The anchor was weighed(!) *Did you weigh it?).

Comment: @Edwin: To my amazement, people really do say [(the) anchor was weighed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weighed+anchor%2Canchor+was+weighed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweighed%20anchor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canchor%20was%20weighed%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Mea culpa. 'The car had alloy wheels' *'Alloy wheels were had by the car.' 'The soldiers broke camp.' *'When did they break it?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four examples are grammatical, but have different underlying constructions.  It is necessary to use an article -- if you mean "secret" to be a noun.  It is necessary not to use an article if you mean "secret" to be an adjective.